# How to include my base template with custom context in Django comment templates?

Tags: django, templates, url, comments, django-context

I have included Django comments framework in my project, and added custom templates to include my base template instead of the default one.

However, in my base template, there are a few url template tags with dynamic parameters:

```
{% url galleries blog.pk blog.slug %}
```

Variable *blog* is included in the context in my views, but not in the comments framework, which causes *No reverse match* error when I try to add a comment.

What would be the best way to get variable *blog* always included in the base template?

Update:

url patterns for blog app:

```
url(r'^(?P<blog_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\-\d\w]+)/galleries/$', 'galleries', name = 'galleries'),
(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create yourself a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors). These are just functions that return a `dict` whose items will be available anywhere in your templates. Typically you will create a `context_processor.py` file in the relevant Django app, then include this in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

E.g.:

project/myapp/context_processors.py:

```
def blog(request):
    return {
        'blog': get_blog(),
    }
```

In your settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ... standard django ones here ...
    'project.myapp.context_processors.blog',
)
```

Now `blog` will be available in all your templates.

EDIT: I forgot that these context processor methods receive the `request` as an argument which lets you do more powerful stuff.

EDIT 2: Per your update showing the URL patterns... You could create a piece of middleware that picked off the `blog_id` from the kwargs and add it to the request object:

```
class BlogMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
         blog_id = view_kwargs.pop('blog_id', None)
         if blog_id:
             request.blog = Blog.objects.get(id=blog_id)
```

Now you can access the blog in the templates using either `{{ request.blog }}` or you could use the context processor still.

Comment: I have considered context_processors, but there is a problem with defining get_blog() function. My blog variable is determined from url retrieved from db, and then checked for user access rights. I don't think I can do this for comment framework urls, as they do not contain blog id.

Comment: I edited the answer to show that these processors receive the request variable. That means you could actually get the URL and therefore the blog id for lookup.